# Error Handling in R when implementing association test

Tags: r, try-catch

I am implementing a zero-inflated negative binomial in R. The code is here:

```
> ICHP<-read.table("ichip_data_recodeA.raw",header=TRUE)
 ICHPdt<-data.table(ICHP)
 covfile<-read.table("sorted.covfile.to.glm.out",header=TRUE)
 covfiledt<-data.table(covfile)
 library(pscl)
 fhandle<-file("ichip_zi_nb_model_scoretest.csv","a")
 for (i in seq(7, ncol(ICHPdt), 1)) {
     notna<-which(!is.na(ICHPdt[[i]]))
     string<-eval(parse(text = paste("ICHPdt$", colnames(ICHPdt)[i], sep="")))
     nullglmmod<-zeroinfl(formula=OverllTot0[notna] ~ EurAdmix[notna] + Sex[notna] + DisDurMonths[notna] + BMI[notna] + Group[notna] + SmokingStatus[notna], data=covfiledt, dist="negbin")
     nullsum<-coef(summary(nullglmmod))
     glmmod<-zeroinfl(formula=OverllTot0[notna] ~ EurAdmix[notna] + Sex[notna] + DisDurMonths[notna] + BMI[notna] + Group[notna] + SmokingStatus[notna] + ICHPdt[[i]][notna], data=covfiledt, dist="negbin")
     summ <- coef(summary(glmmod))
     rownames(summ$zero)[8] <- paste0("ICHPdt$", colnames(ICHPdt)[i])
     rownames(summ$count)[8] <- paste0("ICHPdt$", colnames(ICHPdt)[i])
     writeLines("zero", con=fhandle)
     writeLines(colnames(ICHPdt)[i], fhandle)
     write.table(round(summ$zero, 4), file=fhandle)
     writeLines("count", con=fhandle)
     writeLines(colnames(ICHPdt)[i], fhandle)
     write.table(round(summ$count, 4), file=fhandle)
 }
```

The script errors when i=9246, and issues the following:

```
Error in solve.default(as.matrix(fit$hessian)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.12288e-19
```

Overall, I need to go through ~100,000 markers, so I should expect ~11 such errors.

I would like to help implementing options, for instance with `tryCatch()` for catching such an error, skipping that marker, and moving on.

Comment: I suppose the simplest way to phrase the question is "how can I alter the script such that any value that results in a computationally singular system will be skipped and the script will proceed to the next line.

I have been trying tryCatch, but without much success...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading [this page](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912) for a quick primer and [this page](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html) for a more complete explanation of error handling, and you should eventually read `?conditions`, but in short, there are two ways to handle errors.  The first is with a try-catch, as in:

```
AS.NUMERIC <- function(x){

    # for use in the warning handler
    expectedWarning <- FALSE

    result = tryCatch({
        # a calculation that might raise an error or warning 
        as.numeric(x)
    }, warning = function(w) {

        # the typical way to identify the type of 
        # warning is via it's message attribure
        if(grepl('^NAs introduced by coercion',w$message)){
            cat('an expected warning was issued\n')
            # assign the expected value using the scoping assignment
            expectedWarning <<- TRUE
        }else 
            cat('an unexpected warning was issued\n')
        # reissue the warning
        warning(w)
    }, error = function(e) {
        cat('an error occured\n')
        # similar things go here but for handling errors

    }, finally = {
        # stuff goes here that should happen no matter what, 
        # such as closing connections or resetting global 
        # options such as par(ask), etc.
    })

    # you can handle errors similarly
    if(expectedWarning)
        result <- 5

    return(result)
}


AS.NUMERIC('5')
#> [1] 5
AS.NUMERIC('five') # raises a warning
#> an expected warning was issued
#> [1] 5
#> Warning message:
#> In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
#>   NAs introduced by coercion
```

The second way is to use `try()`, which is less nuanced:

```
x = try(stop('arbitrary error'),# raise an error
        silent=TRUE)

# if there is an error, x will be an object with class 'try-error' 
if(inherits(x,'try-error'))
    # set the default value for x here
    x = 5
```